# Equivalent statements to the Archimedean property

Tags: real-analysis

I was given a set of statements by my lecturer equivalent to the Archimedean property. However, I cannot see how the following is equivalent to the Archimedean property (AP).
Given any real number x, there exists an integer k such that:

$$x-1 ≤ k < x, \quad k \in \Bbb Z, \quad x \in \Bbb R $$

The other statement is that for for all $x \in \Bbb R$, $x > 0$ there exists an $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $n > x$. This is clearly equivalent to the AP. Please can someone explain how the first statement is equivalent to the Archimedian Property.

Comment: Without quantifiers it really doesn't make sense to write things like $x-1<k<x$.

Comment: Poste edit:  that claim is false if $x$ is an integer. You need one or the other inequality to be weak.  Also, I would have thought you would demand uniqueness as part of the property.

Comment: So the statement is not equivalent to the Archimedian postulate and that claim is false in itself anyways?

Comment: You wrote the claim incorrectly.

Comment: As $x$ is positive and $n>x$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there is a minimal $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n-m<x$. Can you show yourself that $x-1\leq n-m$?

Comment: @Andijvie What does that mean, minimal m in N? If m>x then that makes sense but how can i just take an m>x?

Comment: The $m$ is minimal for the property that $n-m<x$. That is, it is the smallest $m$ for which $n-m<x$ is true. Any non-empty subset of $\mathbb{N}$ always has a smallest element. The set $\left\{m\in\mathbb{N}\mid n-m<x\right\}$ is non-empty, as it contains $n$. It therefore has a smallest element and that element we call $m$.

Comment: @Andijvie, how is x - 1 ≤ n - m?

Comment: If $x-1>n-m$, then $x>n-m+1=n-(m-1)$ which contradicts the fact that we chose $m$ to be the smallest natural number such that $x>n-m$.